# Why can't I ask a question?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I haven't asked any question in years on History SE.

But I can't ask a new question because I got "You have reached your question limit"

Why is that?

https://history.stackexchange.com/users/14698/joe-jobs

Comment: From our Help Centre: [Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans)

Comment: Now I remember asking a few questions this year about Pumapunku and the likes. They were deleted. There are only 2 questions left and I have no idea how to improve them

Comment: It looks like you asked 10 questions, 8 of which were deleted.

Comment: You asked 4 questions on May 23/24 that were closed and subsequently deleted. This triggers a block by the SE system, which is outside our control. In general, our advice is to work with the users to fix up a question that's been put on hold rather than starting new ones, in order to avoid this.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think I better remain blocked since my abilities practically did not change. It is better for everyone if I stay out.